# XML message in JAVA

Tags: java, xml-serialization

I was just wondering that is there any way top send the entire XML mesasge as a parameter to a method in Java.
Please let me know if there is any online help avaible on this.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass whole org.w3c.dom.Document as method parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just like you pass any other parameter to a method.

```
public void myMethod(MyXMLMessage xmlMessage){    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An "XML Message" can be *serialized* and wrapped in a `String` object, so this could work:

```
public void receiveXML(String message);
```

Or it has been parsed, usually to a `Document` type:

```
public void receiveDocument(Document parsedMessage);
```

---

A usual way to process XML is to read the *serialized* document (XML Format) from an input stream (file based or receiving from a socket) and use a SAXParser to create a `Document`.